# Sub-template JS asset loading order in Play! framework

Tags: javascript, playframework, dependencies, playframework-2.0

How can I define the load order of javascript assets in the Play framework when I load scripts in sub templates?

In my `index.scala.html` I pull in jQuery:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in my sub template I pull in a script that depends in jQuery:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, `myScript.js` is being loaded before 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js'.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the script as a parameter to your `index.scala.html`.

But I recommend [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). RequireJS enables you to use lazy loading.